# See app changes in real time on real device

Tags: android, eclipse, adt

I have Eclipse with Android Development Kit (ADT) installed, and also SDK. I have connected my Venue7 tabled and enabled USB Debugging.

I've created a simple Hello World app and ran it on my Venue7.

Now is it possible to update the app via Eclipse and see the result @Venue7 in real time? Or do you I have to stop the app and start it again after each change?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you install your program on your device you are doing just that - installing it. The .apk file you have there is an installation package (apk stands for android package) not an executable file. So yes you have to reinstall it each time you have made changes to the program.

On eclipse I believe you just click the run as android program as the other poster said.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using for the first time, Just see the left side, in  package explorer, right click on your package- Select Run As Android application.

You dont need to stop an app. Just Run it from eclipse

Answer (score 1):

If you have made changes in source code and you want to see the effects, you no need to stop the app/device or emulator. But you need to re-run the package again.

You can do this by 2 ways:

1. Right-click project, run as Android application
2. CTRL+F11 is to run the application. But for this you have to apply pre-settings as below.

   Windows>Preferences>Run/debug > Launching : Launch Operation; "Always launch the previously launched application"